# What are all the times Gandalf was either late or early?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, quotes

Gandalf, who is ever-quotable is well known for saying:

> A wizard is never late, nor is he early. He arrives precisely when he means to.

I often cite this to re-assure my friends who're being harsh on themselves for being late or behind on some goal.

But one friend retorted, that "That's a lie. He left the hobbits waiting in Bree, when he was delayed by his meeting with Saruman,"

So I'm wondering what are all the other times where Gandalf was late or early, either in *The Hobbit* or the main trilogy. I'll accept answers including scenes from the movie, but only if they focus on the books.

For the sake of the question, I'm interested in where, from an outside perspective, Gandalf said or implied he'd be somewhere at a fixed time and wasn't there roughly on time – whether deliberate on his part or not.

Comment: He was the "late" Gandalf the Grey after his fight with the Balrog ☜(ﾟヮﾟ☜)

Comment: The premise is a bit problematic since according to Gandalf he just *isn't* "late". We might see his expression as a lame/funny excuse, but it may also point to a deeper understanding of fate than the hobbits (or we) are capable of. The same it's not clear if leaving the hobbits alone in Bree wasn't the best thing to do in the longer scheme of things and thereby also part of a "bigger plan". It really comes down to the definition of "late". We might naively assume "late" according to anyone else, but even then I'd strongly hesitate to construe that as Gandalf lieing, as your friend did.

Comment: @TARS that was sort of my response to my friend. I'm happy to update the question to say from whose perspective of lateness is valid and whose isn't.

Comment: Gríma: "Late is the hour in which this conjurer chooses to appear." -- The Two Towers

Comment: He didn't want to wait until everybody is ready to go. If he arrives just in time he doesn't need to do smalltalk and boring mortal stuff :)

Comment: I guess Gandalf went all the way to Sauron's house before remembering he actually wanted to see Saruman instead, so had go all the way back across town? He wasn't late, just forgetful...

Comment: By his own admission, Gandalf was too late to save Thrain, or to retrieve the last of the Seven (The Council of Elrond).

Comment: I'm amused by the thought of Gandalf being delayed because he met with **Sauron**. "Yeah the Dark Lord just went on and on about ring this and Nazgul that and Gondor blah blah orcs. Ugh! So yeah that's why I was late." He went to meet with **Saruman**, who betrayed and imprisoned Gandalf.

Comment: He left Weathertop early, leaving behind a stone carved with a glyph for Aragorn to find as well (If I remember that right)

Comment: You're looking for book answers about a line Gandalf only says in the movies?

Comment: @IanThompson The thing about Thrain was he had no idea Thrain was there, so he was not late in the sense that he went there hoping to save him.

Comment: @ibid alas, I read the books over twenty years ago, and trying to find out what happened in the movies and not the books wasn't easily done over my lunch break. If only there was a site with experts in LotR media who could kindly help me out... 

Comment: He arrived late when Bilbo invited him for tea, I believe. Quite a faux pas in Hobbiton.

Comment: Is OP assuming that Gandalf intended that line entirely literally, with no hint of jest or exaggeration for effect? In the movie, it seems pretty clear to me that it was _not_ meant as a blanket pronouncement — in which case there's no question of it being ‘a lie’, and no point looking for evidence either way.

Comment: @suchiuomizu --- I know that, but it's an instance (perhaps the only instance) of Gandalf saying (literally) that he was late.

Comment: @gidds The OP is making no such assumption. The OP is trying to assess by how much Gandalf is making jest and exaggerating.

Answer (score 50):

It's hard to catch Gandalf on this, because he'll just retort the second half of the line, that whenever he came actually was when he meant to come.

So you'll have up look for places where Gandalf himself admits to coming at the wrong time.

Gandalf claims that this only happened once, when he failed to meet Frodo at the agreed time.

> And that, Frodo, is the end of my account. May Elrond and the others forgive the length of it. **But such a thing has not happened before, that Gandalf broke tryst and did not
> come when he promised.** An account to the Ring-bearer of so strange an event was required, I think.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book II, Chapter 2 - "The Council of Elrond"</sub>

Comment: Seeing as the Istari are basically angelic beings, he might even be *right* about the second half of the line.

Comment: What event was this? Was it when he failed to meet Frodo in Bree?

Comment: @Skooba Yes, since he was held prisoner by Saruman.

Comment: @Skooba - The plan was actually to meet Frodo in Hobbiton, but yes.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know how he portrays the situation to Saruman and the White Council, but Gandalf is late for their assembly when it comes time to drive Sauron out of [Dol Guldur](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dol_Guldur).  He tells Thorin and Company as much before he sends them into Mirkwood in chapter 7 ("Queer Lodgings) of *The Hobbit*:

> I have, as I told you, some pressing business away south; and I am already late through bothering with you people.  We may meet again before all is over, and then again of course we may not.  That depends on your luck and on your courage and sense; and I am sending Mr. Baggins with you.